# Why does jQuery's append have inconsistent output for carriage returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The examples below demonstrate the question:

```js
$("#ex1").append("\r"); //This one works as expected
$("#ex2").append("\n"); //This also works as expected
$("#ex3").append("\r\n"); //This also works as expected
$("#ex4").append("\r <el></el>"); //This replaces \r with \n
$("#ex5").append("\r\n <el></el>"); //This removes \r completely

$("div").on("click", function() { 
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.innerHTML)); 
});
```

```html
<!-- Note: this also works in the JQuery 2.0 branch -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click the divs below to see the result.
<div id="ex1">R: </div>
<div id="ex2">N: </div>
<div id="ex3">RN: </div>
<div id="ex4">R + El: </div>
<div id="ex5">RN + El: </div>
```

Why does jQuery's append have inconsistent output for carriage returns?

Using the DOM directly, appending text nodes and such, the `\r` is retained (at least on Chrome, on Linux):

```js
document.getElementById("ex1").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\r"));

document.getElementById("ex2").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));

document.getElementById("ex3").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\r\n"));

document.getElementById("ex4").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\r "));
document.getElementById("ex4").appendChild(document.createElement('el'));

document.getElementById("ex5").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\r\n "));
document.getElementById("ex5").appendChild(document.createElement('el'));

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (/^ex\d$/.test(e.target.id)) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e.target.innerHTML));
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- Note: this also works in the JQuery 2.0 branch -->
Click the divs below to see the result.
<div id="ex1">R: </div>
<div id="ex2">N: </div>
<div id="ex3">RN: </div>
<div id="ex4">R + El: </div>
<div id="ex5">RN + El: </div>
```

Comment: You're seeing what the browser does - doesn't have anything to with jQuery really.

Comment: @Pointy: That doesn't appear to be true. Convert those last two to raw DOM calls adding a text node followed by adding an element, and the `\r` is preserved (on Chrome on Linux), but not if you do it through jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah well the "sniffing" that jQuery does to decide what's being appended may have something to do with it, probably.

Comment: OP what is it that you're trying to achieve? Both `\r` and `\n` are white space characters.

Comment: @Pointy I came across this issue because I was working on one of our legacy systems that had `\r\n` in values in a select box (horrible, but true). I was trying `$("select").append("<option value=" + val + ">" + text + "</option>");`. And it wasn't producing the correct result. I realize now that I could do `$("select").append($("<option>").val(val).text(text))`, but I was curious why it didn't work.

Comment: jQuery uses several regular expressions internally to recognize whitespace and line breaks etc, and it does things like `val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" )` to normalize the content in certain methods, and `rCRLF = /\r?\n/g` etc.

Comment: @adeneo: Wanna make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/19gc7pjt/3/

It is not jQuery's problem.

I think it is javascript related browser problem.

(IE use '\r', the others use '\n'. I tested on Chrome btw...)

You can see exactly same result in alert windows. 
'\r' is ignored.

```
$("#ex1").append("\r"); //This one works as expected
$("#ex2").append("\n"); //This also works as expected
$("#ex3").append("\r\n"); //This also works as expected
$("#ex4").append("\r <el></el>"); //This replaces \r with \n
$("#ex5").append("\r\n <el></el>"); //This removes \r completely

var text4 = "\r <el></el>";
var text5 = "\r\n <el></el>";

alert(text4);    //check this
alert(text5);    //and this

$("div").on("click", function () {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.innerHTML));
});
```

Comment: If you call `alert` without using `JSON.stringify`, the carriage return is treated as a white space character. It's still there, just not visible.